# Write out all of the multiplication schemes for four numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ in that order.

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:** Write out all of the multiplication schemes for four numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ in that order.

**My Attempt:** By explicating listing the elements we get the answer as $5$.

$$  (((a_1a_2)a_3)a_4) $$
$$  ((a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)) $$
$$  ((a_1(a_2a_3))a_4)$$
$$  (a_1((a_2a_3)a_4))$$
$$  (a_1(a_2(a_3a_4))) $$

**Doubt:** Is my answer correct? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Tried permutation via gap method?

Comment: AND your 1st and 3rd combination are the same.

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh Sorry for the typos. What is the permutation via gap method?

Comment: There is a better way as you suspect. You are looking for [Catalan numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $$C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$ in this case there are $3$ pairs of brackets so $n=3$ and $C_3=\frac{1}{4}\binom{6}{3}=5$ as you correctly state.

Comment: @N.Shales Thanks man. This was what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: Your answer, 5, is correct. Beyond brute force listing them all you might want to check the Catalan numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much will this help, but consider this
$$(X,a_{1},X,a_{2},X,a_{3},X,a_{4},X)$$
suppose we  have to put 2 braces . We will take any 2 positions out of 5. Using **5C2**.  Now suppose you put 2 around $a_{1}$ and $a_{3}$. It will look like,  $$(X,a_{1},X,a_2,X,a_3,X)a_4$$

Now again the same situation, 2 braces. 4 places. 
: **4C2**
One may go on and on and on..(One may improvise on this one. Cheers)

Comment: This is not my question mate. An opening bracket also has to end

Comment: Yes, that is what I am talking about? 2 braces: '(' and ')'

Comment: Does this method ultimately give $5$, which is indeed correct?